# Is there an shortcut way to deserialize protobuf base classes

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net version 2.3.2.0.

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]
[ProtoInclude(12, typeof(SubClass))]
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public string PropertySub { get; set; }
}
```

As my base class is inherited from many child classes.
How can I avoid placing attribute `[ProtoInclude]` on my base classes so that props in my base class deserialize as expected.

Comment: There is none as far as I know. But you can build your model completely at runtime (exploring your classes with reflection).

Comment: @Evk Ok.. Let me check on this. Thanks